# Script for downloading and installing bumpy 1.8.0

Tags: python

I want to download numpy 1.8.0 from below link unzip and install the Python module, can someone please help me with the script, without mentioning the file name how should I gunzip ?

https://pypi.python.org/packages/73/46/c5b5c61fccec607dad15a2d1f832dec1a8d094ea770d8f8e4a43abd8be7b/numpy-1.8.0.tar.gz#md5=2a4b0423a758706d592abb6721ec8dcd

Comment: You can't extract a file without providing a name. If you want to extract name from the url then you can use this.. `url.split('/')[-1].split("#")[0]`

Comment: you can use tar -zxvf to extract instead of gunzip. The link has tar file.